# Help with Wordpress Custom Nav Walker

Tags: menus, navigation, walker

[image][image: Navigaion Menustrong text]

I want to convert my navigation menu in custom wordpress theme, I have created the design using html/css and now for the naviation bar I want to make it dynamic so it can be manipulated from wordpress dashboard.

The drop is multi level and have custom classes and multuiple html tags. I have called the wp nav menu in my header.php but now I am confused how to make  code for custom nav walker for my given html and css classes.

When I don't add any walker and only call the p nav fucntion the result looks like Image 2

---

### here is my code for html:

```
    <div class="nav-btn">
        <div class="nav-links">

        <?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'menu_haupt' ) ) : -->
            wp_nav_menu(
                array(
                    'theme_location'    => 'menu_haupt',
                    'container_class'   => 'menu-haupt',
                    'items_wrap'        => '<ul>%3$s</ul>',
                    'walker'        => new NavWalkerMainMenu()
                )
            );
            endif; 
            ?> 


            <ul>
                <li class="nav-link">
                    <a href="#" class="no-wrap">Portfolio <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i> </a>
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <div class="arrow"></div>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="dropdown-link">
                                <a href="#" class="no-wrap">FinanzPlaner Online</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown-link">
                                <a href="#" class="no-wrap">FinanzPlaner Offline<i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i> </a>
                                <div class="dropdown second">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li class="dropdown-link">
                                            <a href="#" class="no-wrap">Men�punkt</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="dropdown-link">
                                            <a href="#" class="no-wrap">Men�punkt</i> </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <div class="arrow"></div>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown-link">
                                <a href="#" class="no-wrap">Integrationen/Schnittstellen</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown-link">
                                <a href="#" class="no-wrap">Wissensdatenbank</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-link">
                    <a href="#" class="no-wrap">Akademie</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-link">
                    <a href="#" class="no-wrap">Service & Tools</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-link">
                    <a href="#" class="no-wrap">�ber uns</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="nav-leftBtn">
            <a href="" class="btn-solid"><span class="no-wrap">Finanzplaner online</span> testen</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hamburger-menu-container">
        <div class="hamburger-menu">
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I don't see anything in your design that requires a custom nav walker, unless you're dead set on using those specific HTML class names rather than the ones WordPress already provides. Your `<i>` tags for the icons can be done using the CSS after pseudo selector, e.g. `li:after { content: ''; background: ....; height: ...; etc.. }`

Comment: I edited the post. when I dont add any walker class the menu looks like the 2nd picture.
I want to do something that when I add menus or submenus from  wordpress dashboard they get my custom html structure on each menu/submenu and also the css classes

Comment: I still don't see anything in there that requires a custom nav walker. What you want can be done entirely with CSS with no nav walker, _you don't need custom HTML classes to do this design_. Just add a standard nav menu with `wp_nav_menu` then style it with css to look like the first image. WordPress provides lots of HTML classes on nav menus that you can use to do this already

Comment: can you please write it how can I assign my css classes to the ul,li,a,div,i tags?
can anyone please write the wp_nav_menu for this html? I am really confused.

Comment: you don't need to, e.g. your HTML uses `.nav-link`, ignore that, WP gives you `.menu-item` as well as lots of other classes, use `.menu-item` instead. You don't need those specific HTML classes to implement this design. Similarly every single `a` tag has a `no-wrap` class on it in your HTML, just replace `.no-wrap {` with `.menu a {` in your stylesheet. Don't make the WP nav menu match your HTML, it's much easier to style what `wp_nav_menu` gives you already to look like your design

Comment: and which class of pre-defined nav menu i should use for sub-level ul and li.
and when I hover over li element a div shows with rounded borders and this div have sub level list inside

 <div class="dropdown">
                        <div class="arrow"></div>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="dropdown-link">
                                <a href="#" class="no-wrap">

so how will I achieve this div hide and show in prefined nav menu

because it generates

ul>li>a then ul>li>a 

and there is no div in between

Comment: you should inspect the output `wp_nav_menu` gives you, the HTML classes it provides are too many to list here, and there are multiple classes that can be used in a stylesheet to achieve the same thing. Also as I said earlier, you don't need extra divs for arrows, use CSS pseudo selectors and pseudo-elements instead, e.g. `after` or `before`. You don't need the HTML structure or the HTML classes you've chosen to achieve the design you want. E.g. `ul` tags can have padding and rounded corners too. Anyway, pure CSS frontend styling is better asked on stackoverflow